# Can any one point me to this "Take a picture" widget in google plus android app. Want to know how to create a UI of that type

Tags: android-widget, android, google-plus

[image]

Can any one help me out how how this widget can be developed as in attached.The widget in the attached is of "Take a photo" or select photo" UI. Just want to know how can we create this UI widget. Any tutorials/and discussions/reference would help.Thank You.

Comment: Can any one can help me understand this widget please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how the xml would look like. You'd have to have a background for the FrameLayout and also 2 for the buttons. One with a full rectangle and the other without the top line. Then some margins/paddings tweaking and you should be fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" android:background="#444" android:textColor="#fff" android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" android:background="#444" android:textColor="#fff"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Note: this is based on Mice's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use hierarchyviewer tool from Android SDK. I tried.

You can learn that this menu is a custom baked dialog or activity, created from FrameLayout, ScrollView, LinearLayout and Buttons.

So to make one, you'll have to roll your own in similar style.

[image]

Comment: is there any xml/layout reference for it..?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its native android widget. May be you can find it on github try searching over there.

Comment: hey thanks for the reply. But i have seen this in 4-5 apps.I don't think that its not native. May be google have introduced in new api level > 8, also had a look on github and android forums but no luck.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use [GreenDroid](https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid) library, it has what you are looking for. It is a nice library with host of features. To test it download this sample [application](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.cyrilmottier.android.gdcatalog)